# Zend Framework 2 Controller and FactroyInterface

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

From my Factory i am passsing serviceLocator to the controller, but it seems like ObservationFactory is not being called even i have included in the module.config.php file of the Module

Here is my ObservationController.php

```
    class ObservationController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $em;
    public function __construct($ob)
    {
        $this->em = $ob->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
    }
```

here is ObservationFactory.php

```
    class ObservationFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $controller = new ObservationController($serviceLocator->getServicelocator());
        return $controller;
    }
}
```

and in Module.config.php

```
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Observation\Controller\ObservationController' => 'Observation\Controller\ObservationFactory'
    ),
    'invokables' => array(
            'Observation\Controller\Observation'=> Controller\ObservationController::class
    ),
),
```

> Missing argument 1 for Observation\Controller\ObservationController::__construct(), called in S:\xampp\htdocs\v3\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 207 and defined in S:\xampp\htdocs\v3\module\Observation\src\Observation\Controller\ObservationController.php on line 47
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: ob in
>   S:\xampp\htdocs\v3\module\Observation\src\Observation\Controller\ObservationController.php
>   on line 49
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on
>   unknown in

Comment: What happens if you change your controller factories entry into `ObervationController::class => ObervationControllerFactory::class`? Maybe your invokables trouble your factory. What happens if you leave out the invokables section in your controller array?

Comment: Yes that invokables was the issue, removed it and now the factory works

Comment: Since you are already injecting the `ServiceLocatorInterface` into your controller just to grab the entitymanager, why wont you use proper dependency injection and just inject the entitymanager into your controller instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `ObservationController` is taking an argument in its constructor, you do not need to call your controller as `invokables` any more. It would not work. Because an invokable class can not be constructed with arguments.

Whereas whenever you need argument(s) for your controller, you should make a factory for that controller what you already did. Just hide or remove the `ObservationController` under the `invokables` key as the following

```
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Observation\Controller\Observation' => 'Observation\Controller\ObservationFactory'
    ),
    'invokables' => array(
        // 'Observation\Controller\Observation'=> Controller\ObservationController::class
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prepare your code for ZF3, use this structure :

```
return [
    'controllers' => [
        'aliases' => [
            'Observation\Controller\Observation' => Observation\Controller\ObservationController::class,
        ],
        'factories' => [
            Observation\Controller\ObservationController::class => Observation\Controller\ObservationControllerFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: This is not enough, since he has to change his factory to implement the new factory pattern: `public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null);`

Comment: Yes, but your FactoryInterface is not compatible with ServiceManager 2. This custom Interface can work in both cases :
`interface FactoryInterface
        {
            public function __invoke(/*ContainerInterface*/ $container);
        }`

Comment: He just has to implement the `__invoke` method together with his `createService` method and it will be compatible. He just can copy his `createService` stuff into `__invoke` and call it from `createService` like: `return $this($serviceLocator, Controller\ObservationController::class);`